# TableView is not showing string when jar file is run in a separate directory

Tags: java, netbeans, javafx, jar, tableview

I have JAVAFX based code that I compiled and tested from netbeans.

The directory tree looks like this:

```
myCodeDir/
    src/
        myCode/
            *.java
             *.fxml 
    dist/
        myCode.jar
        myCode.jnlp
```

If I copy the jar file to another directory and run jar file from within that directory, I see that TableView is not showing any data while size command shows total number of data accurately which means TableView has data.

However, if I run the jar code from `myCodeDir` itself, everything is alright.

I need to distribute tje jar file to other machine so it is required to make the code runnable from any directory. How can I do that?

Comment: If you run the jar file from the command line, do you see any exceptions?

Comment: It seems likely that you are using a relative file name.  Place your data inside your .jar file and access it using [Class.getResource](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource-java.lang.String-).

Comment: @james_D, I want to run from command line. I do not see any exception. Even I checked total number of entries for the ComboBox which is ok.  If I run from the netbeans project area, then everything is working nicely.

Comment: @VGR, I tried but getting exception. For `dictName = rootDir + "/" + DICTPathDir + "/" + fName; inDictStr = getClass ().getResourceAsStream (dictName);   inDictStrReader = new InputStreamReader (inDictStr); try { br = new BufferedReader (inDictStrReader); String line; while ((line = br.readLine ()) != null) {...` I get exceptions.

Comment: @VGR, Actually `InputStream inDictStr = getClass().getResourceAsStream (dictName);` gives `inDictStr=null` which gives exception. But `br = new BufferedReader (dictName);` reads file properly.

Comment: A resource path is *not* a filename, it’s a relative URL whose base is each location in the classpath.  See http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/2433/resources-on-classpath#t=201701111734535687024&a=remarks .

Comment: @VGR, Thanks for the illustration. Since I am newbie, I still have confusion. I wish to read a file `myCodeDir/dict/dict.01`. I thought path with filename be argument to `getResourceAsStream`. Please kindly tell me how may I write.

Comment: I am using `dictName="dict/dict.01"; ClassLoader thisCL = MainScreenController.class.getClassLoader(); InputStream inDictStr = thisCL.getResourceAsStream(dictName);`

Comment: First, inspect the .jar file and make sure dict.01 is present in the .jar file.  Then pass the exact path of the dict.01 .jar entry (not the path to the file, the .jar entry name) to the getResourceAsStream method.

Comment: I copied dict.01 to src/package_name/. After compilation, I see dict.01 is shown in the `.jar` file as `packageName/dict/dict.01` while `dict.01` is in `src/packageName/dict' directory. I am passing `dict/dict.01` and not `packageName/dict/dict.01`. I tried with `/dict/dict.01` also, yet in vain.

Comment: Dear @VGR, I am grateful to you for your continuous teaching to a newbie like me. It is working. I am using `dict/dict01`.  Thank you very much.